# Converting string to float with "," as thousands separator.. "123,000.12" to 123,000.12

Tags: python, xlwt

I can't perform any math operations on these values that I had exported. I'm using `xlwt` library to do this. Any way to convert these values in the format so that I can be able to perform math operations on it.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
float('3629,473.237'.replace(',', ''))
```

Comment: Please don't use curly quotes  use straight ones

Comment: @WasifHasan I’m on iPhone, I don’t know how.

Comment: I have edited the answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the commas, they make no sense except readablity

```
n = float("3629,473.237".replace(",",""))
```

To re-add commas as string, you can use format strings:

```
print("{:,}".format(n))
```

There are f-strings in python 3.6+

```
print(f"{n:,}")
```

Comment: I need this commas as well. It is an requirement from our client. Any other solution?

Comment: See the edit pls

Answer (score 0):

No; you'll have to remove the comma manually.

```
float("123,000.12".replace(',',''))
```

If you have consistent data, you might as well remove all the commas and convert the result.